# installation of gnuhealth client $ pip3 install --user --upgrade gnuhealth-client

Tags: python, linux, centos7, tryton

the error msg :

```
Building wheel for PyGObject (PEP 517) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpnfra__iq
           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-4p2n3fm2/pygobject
      Complete output (43 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygtkcompat
      copying pygtkcompat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygtkcompat
      copying pygtkcompat/generictreemodel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygtkcompat
      copying pygtkcompat/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygtkcompat
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
      copying gi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
      copying gi/_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
      copying gi/_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
      copying gi/_error.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
      copying gi/_gtktemplate.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
      copying gi/_option.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
      copying gi/_ossighelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
      copying gi/_propertyhelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
      copying gi/_signalhelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
      copying gi/docstring.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
      copying gi/importer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
      copying gi/module.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
      copying gi/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
      copying gi/types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/repository
      copying gi/repository/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/repository
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/GIMarshallingTests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/GLib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/GObject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/Gdk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/GdkPixbuf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/Gio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/Gtk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/Pango.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/keysyms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
      running build_ext
      Package cairo-gobject was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo-gobject.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      No package 'cairo-gobject' found
      Command '('pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'cairo-gobject >= 0')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyGObject
    Failed to build PyGObject
    ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyGObject which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Answer (score 1):

You should install pygobject from your distribution package. Otherwise you need to install all the required headers for cairo and probably GTK.